# Which types are nihilistic?

Tags: type-theory

[Note 2020-02-08: I updated the definition of nihilistic types so that it relies less on the type `Empty`.]

A [discussion on Twitter](https://twitter.com/andrejbauer/status/1225702461471690752?s=20) prompted the following question, which I have never seen considered before.

**Definition:** Say that a type `T` is **inhabited** if there exists a closed term of type `T`, and  **empty** otherwise.

We assume that there is an empty type, or else the rest of the question is not very interesting. For instance, we might have the type `Empty` which is in fact empty.

**Definition:** Say that a type `T` is **nihilistic** if every closed term `t` of type `T` contains a subexpression of an empty type.

I think (but have not thought carefully) that a type is nihilistic if and only if every *normalized* closed terms contains a subexpression of an empty type.

Clearly, every empty type is nihilistic.

> **Question:** *Which inhabited types are nihilistic, if any?*

For example `Empty → Empty` seems like a good candidate for a nihilistic type.

Comment: Though this might be somewhat flexible, do you have a type system in mind for your question, say System F?

Comment: System F sounds complicated. Try simply typed $\lambda$-calculus first. In any case, I think the question isn't that complicated.

Comment: could you please give an example of a term which belongs to the said nihilistic type?

Comment: @ApoorvIngle: $\lambda x : \mathsf{Empty} . x$ has type $\mathsf{Empty} \to \mathsf{Empty}$ and it contains the subexpression $x$ of type $\mathsf{Empty}$.

Comment: Hi Andrej, I like this question. I think that `(T → Empty) → Empty` is also nihilistic by this definition, for any `T`, so that's a big source of nihilistic types.

Comment: I think I got my definition slightly wrong, let me fix it.

Comment: This question also vaguely reminds me of the notion of "nowhere-unit typing" from http://noamz.org/papers/imploid-flows.pdf, which is inspired by the notion of "nowhere-zero flow" in graph theory.  That's defined as a property of typings rather than of types, but in a sense it corresponds to a dual form of "ultranihilism": a nowhere-unit typing of a term is one such that no subterm is assigned a type above the unit type, i.e., every subterm receives an empty type.

Comment: Hmm.. if `T` is nihilistic, then so is `T' -> T`.  As for inhabited nihilistic types, not sure how to caracterize them exhaustively, but it seems that intuitively, if `T'` is empty, then `T' -> T` should be inhabited.

Comment: @Stefan: can you *prove* any of your observations?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: No, the first was wrong (I think it's true that `T' -> T` is nihilistic if `T` is empty since the term will be a function whose body is a term which must have type `T`, but it doesn't generalizes to the case where `T` is nihilistic) and the second just seems like it should be true (if you turn "`T'` is empty" into "there's a closed term `P : T' -> Empty`" and `Empty` accepts the principle of explosion, then you can use `P` to build a term of type `T' -> T`).

Comment: @AndrejBauer: Thanks for the example. I do not understand why you would need an `Empty` type, Isn't $\cdot, x : Empty \vdash M : \tau$ vacuously true for all $M, \tau$? Sec 3.2: https://doi.org/10.1016/0890-5401(88)90009-0 OR i am missing something..